# How do I get the path of a file in an eclipse project?

Tags: java, eclipse

My project in eclipse:

```
MyJavaProject
|
|___src/main/java
|     |
|     |___myPackage
|           |
|           |___myJava.java
| 
|___myFolder
|     |
|     |___myFile.txt
|
.
.
.
```

To read myFile.txt from myJava code, I used the path `/MyJavaProject/myFolder/myFile.txt`. This path  always gives me file not found exception. What is the mistake here ?

Comment: Delete the leading slash.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen - still does not work. same error.

Comment: Note that after you have created a File object, you can invoke `file.getAbsolutePath()` to see what you have constructed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

generally when you launch Main class in eclipse, it sets current directory to root of project

you can check it via

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"))
```

so you need relative path from root of your project

Comment: Can be overriden in the launch configuraiton

Comment: yes you can set working directory in run configuration

Comment: Thanks. That helps a bit. But it does not get me to the exact file location. I appended my relative path to the path 
from your code. I get file not found.

Comment: could you please post the current working directory and what you appended to that and what is the final string it resolves to ?

Answer (score 0):

You can read it like this :

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("myFolder/myFile.txt")));
    while(true)
            {
                String line = br.readLine();
                if(line == null)
                    break;
                else
                {
                    System.out.println(line);   
                }

            }
```

Answer (score -1):

In Eclipse all java files in `src/main/java/` are compiled and copied to your output folder `/bin or /target/classes`, so when your `myJava.java` is executed the working directory of the java class is either "bin/" or `/target/classes`.  And from those directories it will not have access to your file as `/MyJavaProject/myFolder/myFile.txt`.  Your options are below:

- Use a relative path, new File( `../myFolder/myFile.txt` ) or `../../myFolder/myFile.txt` depending on your output folder
- Add the `myFolder` as a subfolder of the `src/main/java` and then eclipse will copy those resources to your `/bin` or `/target/classes` output folder and then you can access it using the relative path `myFolder/myFile.txt`
- if you project is a maven project (m2e plugin is installed) then you can use the `src/main/resources/` folder and then eclipse will copy those resources to your output folder in the same way.